# Tomcat 8 | How to use custom Key Manager for connector

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keystore

I created my custom "dynamic" Key Manager (extends X509ExtendedKeyManager).
Since I update my server key from time to time, I want to be able to reload my private key **without** restarting the connector.

My trust store is also update frequently - and I manage to support the same issue with defining the connector (server.xml) with the trustManagerClassName attribute, using my custom "dynamic" trust manager.

Can I do the same with the key manager?
I didn't find any attribute on the connector for this
(https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: I think (YMMV) you can use the `sslImplementationName` option. You can find some more documentation/an example [here](https://github.com/intercommit/basic-jsp-embed/tree/master/basic-jsp-embed/src/main/java/com/descartes/basicjsp/embed/ssl) (read the java-docs in the files).

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40659748/4080510) is how I managed to solve similar problem. You need to define `sslImplementationName` property of the `<Connector>`, and implement custom `JSSEImplementation` as well as `X509KeyManager` in order to get certificate and private key from any storage you want.