# HSM usage with Apache Tomcat for HTTPS

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, hsm

My HSM (Hardware Security Module) stores (or allows to use) private key, however, it does not support PKCS#11 and similar method. In turn, Apache Tomcat might work with certificate and keys either via JKS, PKCS#11 or programmatically. My goal is to enable HTTPS support on a Web server, but I see no way how to achieve that with changes in configuration files only.

I imagine an option that I could store certificate in JKS, and get private key associated with it via HSM vendor provided API. For that purpose, if I am right, I will need to re-implement [JSSEImplementation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/jsse/JSSEImplementation.html) and corresponding factories. As well, I will need to implement specific Key and Trust Managers.

Is that the only way to solve such problem?

Is it safe to replace JSSEImplementation in a running standalone instance of Apache Tomcat, for instance, right after it started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I came up only to the solution below based on [this](https://github.com/intercommit/basic-jsp-embed/tree/master/basic-jsp-embed/src/main/java/com/descartes/basicjsp/embed/ssl) example. I add `<Connector>` instance to the Tomcat configuration with `sslImplementationName` property pointing to the custom `JSSEImplementation` class name, and extend `JSSEImplementation` with custom `JSSESocketFactory` and `X509KeyManager` classes.

Tomcat configuration looks like:

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS" SSLEnabled="true"
       sslImplementationName="x.y.z.CustomJSSEImplementation"
       keyAlias="alias_of_key_in_HSM_and_cert_in_JKS"
/>
```

`CustomJSSEImplementation` class is:

```
public class CustomJSSEImplementation extends JSSEImplementation {
   @Override
   public ServerSocketFactory getServerSocketFactory(AbstractEndpoint endpoint) {
      return new CustomSslContextSocketFactory(endpoint);
   }

   @Override
   public SSLUtil getSSLUtil(AbstractEndpoint endpoint) {
      return new CustomSslContextSocketFactory(endpoint);
   }
}
```

`CustomSslContextSocketFactory` class is:

```
public class CustomSslContextSocketFactory extends JSSESocketFactory {

    public static final AtomicReference<CustomSslContext> customSslContext =
        new AtomicReference<CustomSslContext>();

    public CustomSslContextSocketFactory(AbstractEndpoint endpoint) {
        super(endpoint);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyManager[] getKeyManagers() throws Exception {
        return (customSslContext.get() == null ? super.getKeyManagers() : customSslContext.get().getKeyManagers(this));
    }
}
```

`CustomSslContext` interface is:

```
interface CustomSslContext {
    KeyManager[] getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory factory) throws Exception;
}
```

`HsmKeyManagerImpl` which reference private key in the HSM by an `keyAlias` property looks like:

```
public class HsmKeyManagerImpl implements X509KeyManager {
    ...

    @Override
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias) {
        // HSM Vendor specific API calls
    }
}
```

I didn't show the code how to obtain certificate which corresponds to the private, but the same alias defined by the `keyAlias` property of the `<Connector>` is used to get it from the JKS.